# insserv: missing `Required-Stop:' entry: please add even if empty

Tags: linux, service, suse, init.d, sysv

In the /etc/init.d/myservice script i have the following lines

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: myserviced
# Required-Start: $syslog
# Required-Stop: $syslog
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description:
# Description: Bring up/down service
### END INIT INFO
```

Inspite of that the following error message is omitted while execting comman **/sbin/chkconfig --add myserviced

```
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script jexec is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
myserviced          0:off  1:off  2:off  3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
```

I had read the post [Incomplete LSB comment. insserv: missing valid name for `Provides:' please add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821380/incomplete-lsb-comment-insserv-missing-valid-name-for-provides-please-add). But was of no help.

This error occurs on SUSE 11 but not on Rehat-6

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your dashes are what is expected. In some copy-pasting I was doing, the interpreter wasn't seeing the expected character. 
So literally, this

```
# Required­Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $time 
# Required­Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $time 
# Should­Start:      $network $named slapd autofs ypbind nscd nslcd 
# Should­Stop:       $network $named slapd autofs ypbind nscd nslcd
```

became this:

```
# Required-­Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $time 
# Required­-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $time 
# Should­-Start:      $network $named slapd autofs ypbind nscd nslcd 
# Should-­Stop:       $network $named slapd autofs ypbind nscd nslcd
```

The first set I copied from a pdf that contained an apparently non-printable character. I manually typed in the - and it worked.

Comment: This solved it for me, should be marked as the answer.

Comment: I might be seen right in nano but leafpad shows it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The bug in in jexec not myservice
It is still there in SLED 11 SP2
You have to add the Required-Stop line to jexec

Comment: its better if you can edit the posted question and show how to do it

Comment: @gluten3 In the original question you can see that the "Required-Stop" line exists and still the jexec throws the warnings. Could you please post some sample template which can fix displaying warnings.